# Can't apply transition effect between clips in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, transitions

This is really annoying me a lot. I have two clips with the exact same properties next to each other. I usually add a 'dip to white' transition between clips, but somehow I can't apply it between those two.

[image]

How is this possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, add your desired transition to your timeline, allowing it to be applied to only one of your clips for now:

[image: screenshot 1]

Select the transition and open the `Effect Controls` panel:

[image: effect controls screenshot]

Finally, from the `Alignment` dropdown, simply select the "Center at Cut" option:

[image: Screenshot 3]

The transition will now be applied to both clips!

[image: final screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

When you apply a transition between two clips, Premiere needs to use the frames of footage for each clip that go to the start and end of the transition. If there's no footage past that point, it won't allow you to apply the transition.

Consider my illustration below.

You may need to have some footage remaining after the end of your clip to allow for this. Re-import or trim your clips to allow some footage to 'show' underneath the dip to white.

[image]

Comment: I struggled with this for hours before finding this answer. It works great!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

It's really simple when you know it :)

Comment: Welcome! Can you summarize the contents of the video in case it becomes unavailable to people who find this in the future?

Comment: This is the best! Thanks 